# Subset rows by number in data table after filtering for one condition

Tags: r, data.table

How can I subset rows in a data table by numbers after having filtered for another condition?

**Clarification:** I want to first filter the data.table for all rows where foo is not NA, and then have the first 50 rows of this pre-filtered data.table returned. I do not (!) want to filter the first 50 rows where foo is not NA (which could return in zero rows returned).

```
dt[!is.na(foo)]
```

works

```
dt[1:50]
```

works as well

How to combine the two?

Answer (score 1):

The use of a second `[`-expression changes the logic. Instead of (in words) *"foo is not NA and the row is in 1-50"*, with two expressions you are saying *"of the rows where foo is not NA, take rows 1-50"*, which is different. For instance, if there are no instances where `foo` is not `NA` in the first 50 rows, your question should return 0-rows but the double `[`-expression will find the first 50 rows where foo is not NA.

I suggest two alternatives.

## Single `[`-expression

```r
dt[!is.na(foo) & seq(.N) %in% 1:50,]
```

In this case I might prefer with `between(seq(.N), 1, 50)` or `seq(.N) <= 50`, depending on a few things, but the premise remains to use `seq(.N)`. (The `.I` special row index is not available in the `i=` argument.)

## Double `[`-expressions

Subset the rows *first*, though this does not generalize as well if you have many other things going on.

```r
dt[1:50,][!is.na(foo),]
```

Answer (score 0):

after trying several combinations...

```
dt[!is.na(foo)][1:50]
```

WORKS!

Comment: To make this more clear you could state `dt[!is.na(foo), ][1:50, ]`.

Comment: Either clarify your question to change the logic, or understand/admit that this is different logic.

Comment: @jay.sf this solution is incorrect. Notice OP is interested in the non-NA values in the first 50 rows. This could be even 10 values. On the other hand, this solution first filters non-na values in the entire dataset, then takes the first 50 values, giving false results.

Comment: This is incorrect

Comment: I rarely downvote, but I've downvoted this question as it is logically wrong (based on the question) and will return different results. I will happily reverse this vote if/when the question and/or this answer are clarified/corrected.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean about "logically wrong". I wanted to subset rows after (!) having filtered for another condition. Which is what you describe in your answer as the second solution.

Comment: I'm saying that the code here does not produce the same results that `dt[!is.na(foo) & 1:50]` is supposed to accomplish. The logic is different. The question in my head is which is wrong: the logic you originally asked (in which case your answer may be what you want/need) or the code you wrote here. Regardless of which is right/wrong, they are different.

Comment: I have edited my question to better reflect my intention. You are right, of course, about `dt[!is.na(foo) & 1:50]` meaning something different. Since I mostly use dplyr syntax, and not base R or data.table subsetting, I kind of assumed something different.

Comment: The clarification seems good, though it reinforces my interpretation that the code in this answer is not correct.

Comment: ...in my R console: `test1 <- dt[!is.na(foo)][1:50]` `test2 <- dt[!is.na(foo),][1:50,]` equals `TRUE` when checked by `all.equal(test1, test2)`

Comment: With `data.table`, the commas in those expressions do little more than provide aesthetic context. The logic in those two expressions is still wrong.

Comment: Two expressions ([ ]+[ ]) containing filters will create subsequent filtering, i.e. filter for one condition first, then filter this result again, correct? It would be logically wrong if it is was inconsistent, right?  Imho, it is consistent with what I want. And also consistent with what you write in your answer? Maybe I am just not getting it, lol. Thanks for your answer and comments though! I have not accepted your answer (yet) because it answers my wrongly formulated, now revised question.